# Зная ID пользователя инстаграм узнать логин

Tags: php, javascript, python, instagram

Приветствую, собственно вопрос такой, узнать логин пользователя Instagram по ID без использования API Instagram. Например есть ссылка https://www.instagram.com/durov/?__a=1 которая дает JSON ответ о странице пользователя, исходя из этого, может быть есть библиотека которая конвертирует ID в логин или что-нибудь похожее?

Comment: За что минусуют, не понятно... Можете воспользоваться js-библиотекой http://instafeedjs.com/ Потребуются логин и пароль пользователя, с которого будете смотреть данные.

Comment: Зачем нужны логины, кроме как на взлом учёток ? Правильно минусят.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так как PHP мне более близок чем JS или Python, нашел библиотеку Instagram PHP Scrapper(https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper). Но там требуется использовать логин и пароль пользователя, как на JS библиотеке которую отправил @DaemonHK. Есть одна проблема, которая решается очень просто, как только Вы введете логин и пароль, и попробуете использовать какую-нибудь функцию, Вы получите ошибку. Она заключается в том что Instagram временно заблокирует профиль, так как вместе с запросом не идут некоторые HTTP заголовки.
В файле

> /vendor/raiym/instagram-php-scraper/src/InstagramScraper/Instagram.php

на 1006 строке есть массив, в этом массиве надо дописать такие заголовки как

```
'accept' => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
'accept-encoding' => "gzip, deflate, br",
'accept-language' => "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
'upgrade-insecure-requests' => "1",
'user-agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; I; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0",
```

Для установки библиотеки на сервер используйте Composer - https://habrahabr.ru/post/145946/

Answer (score 1):

Там в json явно прописан логин (юзернейм) по адресу user.username

Может вставить json в бьютифайер и посмотреть https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

UPDATE: не увидел "без апи". Без АПИ как вы узнаете...

Answer (score 0):

Это очень просто и реализуется на php + curl:

```
    <?php
    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
    Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86";
    $cookie = $username . ".txt"; 


$header=array('Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9','Connection: keep-alive','Cache-control: max-age=0');
       $url =  "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/".$_GET[id]."/info/";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// просто отключаем проверку сертификата 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . $cookie);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . $cookie);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate, br'); // указывает curl что ответ может быть сжат, без этого будут "кракозябры"
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $page = curl_exec($ch);

   $userbyid = json_decode($page,true);
   echo $userbyid['user']['username'];

   // завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов
   curl_close($ch);
   ?>
```